# What exactly is the button "Abandon Change" in gerrit?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gerrit

I didn't find any documentation that can help me out. Can I push to review one commit then another and then abandon first and submit second? We're using Git on our project.

Answer (score 7):

There is some documentation regarding the [abandon option](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html) for command review.

But essentially abandon abandons the change, so it can no longer be committed to the branch unless it is restored.

The change will no longer be counted as an open review, when it is abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. Once you have an abandoned commit you must remove the dependency of future commits on it.
Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947790/git-merge-pending-due-to-an-abandoned-commit) that can tell you how to do it.