# Git merge pending due to an abandoned commit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two commits. Commit B depends on commit A. Commit A was abandoned. Now I am getting error for merging B. It says submitted, merge pending due to dependency of B on A.

I have googled around but cant find an exact answer. I need step by step solution as I am a novice in git and am finding hard to understand how to resolve this.

This is what happened.

1. git commit in local for A.
2. git push for A in remote.
3. A got abandoned, but my local git has commit A.
4. git commit in local for B in same branch (Makes B dependent on A).
5. git push B in remote in same branch.
6. Now B is not merging since A is abandoned.

I need to merge B and I want dependency on A removed. Hope its clear now!

Here is Server error:

> Change 1184 - Submitted, Merge Pending

In comments:

> Gerrit Code Review
>
> Change could not be merged because of a missing dependency. The
>   following changes must also be submitted:
>   (commit-id, which was abandoned)

Will rebase work? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  What is the exact comand you were running?  What is the output?  What are you trying to achieve?  I don't think this can be answered with the information given.

Comment: So by "B is not merging", you mean the server rejects the commit because it's not a direct descendent of the current head on the server?

Comment: could you post the error message?

Comment: @SvenMarnach No Both commits are pushed on server. But A is abandoned, hence not merged and B is not merging because it depends on A.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gerrit, and I have no idea what has been going on there.  If you push a branch to the git server, all commits reachable by a head commit will be automatically included, so I'm not sure how it is even possible to end up in this situation.  My guess is that you will have to call `git fetch` to get the current version of your branch on the server, rebase or cherry-pick your commit B on top of the remote head and then push again.  Since I don't really know what's going on, this is more of an educated guess than an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to fix your problem. Pick whichever you feel most comfortable with.

Here is one:

1. `git checkout yourbranch` (make sure you are on the right branch)
2. `git reset --hard A^` (reset everything to the commit before A)
3. `git cherry-pick B` (where B is the hash of the commit you want to keep)
4. `git log` (confirm that it is what you wanted)
5. `git push --force` (may need to specify other options depending on how you usually push)

Here is another, result is equivalent:

1. `git checkout yourbranch` (make sure you are on the right branch)
2. `git rebase --onto A^ A` (rebase everything after A on top of the commit before A, effectively removing A)
3. `git log` (confirm that it is what you wanted)
4. `git push --force` (may need to specify other options depending on how you usually push)

Here is a third, result still equivalent:

1. `git checkout yourbranch` (make sure you are on the right branch)
2. `git rebase --interactive A^` (will open up your editor)
3. Delete the line showing commit A, save and close
4. `git log` (confirm that it is what you wanted)
5. `git push --force` (may need to specify other options depending on how you usually push)

Comment: Yes, if your history is `X <- A <- B`, then `git rebase --onto X B~1` is synonymous to `git rebase --onto A^ A` (second solution suggested above), because `X` is the commit before `A` (`A^` means `A`'s first parent) and `A` is the commit before `B` (`B~1` is equivalent to `B^`, `B`'s first parent). Nice that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737326/gerrit-change-has-statussubmitted-merge-pending-how-to-solve-it) is an issue like yours.

> If committ B has a dependency on A, then B cannot be merged until A is
>   merged. Since you have abandoned A, Gerrit will not automatically
>   merge B.
>
> What you will need to do is modify B (perhaps using `git rebase`) so
>   that it no longer depends on A, and resubmit the change to Gerrit.

how do I rebase / merge it?

```
git-review -d 1184 
git rebase origin/master
git status
<edit "both modified" files in status report>
git add <files>
git rebase --continue
git review
```

Find more useful information [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/resolve_conflict) about this kind of issue.

Comment: I get 
---
On branch review/vinay_choudhary/1184
nothing to commit, working directory clean
---
on git status.